# Infinite scroll loading Pagination problem in ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pagination

Problem with displaying images in ListView, have error app crash when load all images at once and pagination code i have now is not work for some reason

Basicly want to fetch images from this firebase colection and display them in 'ListView' with pagination to my app not crash.
Hopfuly somebody can help me fix this issue, thank you!

```
initSliderImages() async {
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('galerytab1');
    result.snapshots().listen((data) {
      List imgs = [];
      data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        var imageData = change.doc.data();
        String image = imageData?['url'];
        imgs.add(CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: image));
      });

      setState(() {
        images = imgs;
      });
    });
  }
```

```
class _CategoryTab1State extends State<CategoryTab1> {
  List images = [];

  late ScrollController controller;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // addUrls();
    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
    initSliderImages();
    if (this.mounted) {
      context.read<CategoryTab1Bloc>().data.isNotEmpty
          ? print('data already loaded')
          : context.read<CategoryTab1Bloc>().getData(mounted, widget.category);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    print(controller.position.extentAfter);

    if (controller.position.extentAfter < 2) {
      setState(() {
        print('add 2 more');
        print('add 2 more');
        print('add 2 more');
        print('add 2 more');
        // images.addAll(['item1','item2','item3']
            // List.generate(2, (index) => 'Inserted $index'
        // )
 
        // );
      });
    }
  }

  // //
  // void addUrls() {
  //   final List<String> imgs = List.generate(
  //     16,
  //         (_) {
  //       int random = Random().nextInt(16) + 16; // 250-500
  //       return
  //         // initSliderImages();
  //         // 'https://picsum.photos/$random/$random';
  //           'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/klosterkatz-c914e.appspot.com/o/galerytab1%2F1.png?alt=media&token=5b0e9c74-ec5a-42ca-aa59-309f41938a28';
  //
  //
  //
  //
  //     },
  //   );

  //   setState(() {
  //     images.addAll(imgs);
  //   });
  // }
  //

  // Fetch images from databse for list

  initSliderImages() async {
    final int _limit = 3;

    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('galerytab1');
    result.snapshots().listen((data) {
      List imgs = [];
      data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        var imageData = change.doc.data();
        String image = imageData?['url'];
        imgs.add(image);
      });

      setState(() {
        images = imgs;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('imagesimageimagesimagesimageismageimage');
    print('$images');
    print(images.length);

    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {


        if (notification.metrics.pixels ==
            notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
          initSliderImages();
          _scrollListener();
          // addUrls();
        }

        return true;
      },
      child:
      ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        key: widget.key,
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemExtent: 250,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: images[index],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              key: ValueKey(images[index]),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In listview.Builder add shrinkWrap : primary false if not true

Answer (score 0):

App is crashing due to memory issue. Following code is for proper pagination using firestore. Hope it will help you.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class CategoryTab1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryTab1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoryTab1> createState() => _CategoryTab1State();
}

class _CategoryTab1State extends State<CategoryTab1> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();
  var _images = <String>[];

  /// Flag for first time loading
  var _isLoading = true;

  /// Flag for paginated loading
  var _isSubLoading = false;

  /// last snapshot reference for pagination
  QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? _lastSnapshot;

  /// length of last images fetched
  var _length = 10;

  /// can load more if length is equal or more than 10
  /// if less than 10 it means all images have been fetched
  bool get _canLoadMore => _length >= 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadData();
    _controller.addListener(_listener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(_listener);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _listener() {
    if (!_canLoadMore) {
      return;
    }
    if (_isSubLoading || _isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    if (_controller.position.extentAfter <= 0) {
      _loadData();
    }
  }

  final _collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('galerytab1');

  void _loadData() async {
    try {
      if (_lastSnapshot != null) {
        _isSubLoading = true;
        setState(() {});
      }
      late QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _result;

      /// Fetching images
      if (_lastSnapshot == null) {
        /// First time loading
        _result = await _collection.limit(10).get();
      } else {
        /// Paginated loading
        _result = await _collection
            .startAfterDocument(_lastSnapshot!)
            .limit(10)
            .get();
      }
      final docs = _result.docs;
      _length = docs.length;
      for (final doc in docs) {
        String im = doc.data()['url'] ?? '';
        if (im.isNotEmpty) _images.add(im);
      }
      if (docs.isNotEmpty) _lastSnapshot = docs.last;
    } catch (_) {}
    _isLoading = false;
    _isSubLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              itemCount: _images.length,
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: _images[index],
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  key: ValueKey(_images[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          if (_isSubLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```